# How to include bootstrap-select to a cshtml in Visual Studio Net Core? Nothing shown on page

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-select

I have visual studio community 2019.
I have create a ASP.NET Core Web App project with .NET 5.0.
So bootstrap v4.3.1 is included.

Now I want to add a bootstrap-select drop-down:
https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

I have installed bootstrap-select using NuGet Package manager.

**Question 1**: Do I have to copy some js files now or update any configuration because in wwwroot/js or wwwroot/lib the bootstrap-select.js file is not available.

**Question 2**: See code below. I have added a select item but nothing is shown on the page? Why?

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}


<select class="selectpicker from-control" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).read(function () {
        $('select').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you, You can use either CND from that provider into your layout page, Or you can copy and paste all necessary files into wwwroot folder and include them into the layout page.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>
```

But ultimately you need to include that into the layout page and also need to add javascript or jquery like this to make it work.

```
$('.your-dropdown-class').selectpicker();
```